# Can this be considered a definition of a cone?

Tags: geometry, definition, tangent-line

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_lines_to_circles) is a Wikipedia article about tangent lines to circles. It states that

> In Euclidean plane geometry, a tangent line to a circle is a line that touches the circle at exactly one point, never entering the circle's interior.

**Does this definition also apply to lines that lie in different planes to that of the circle?** I am not sure but I think that the definition of a tangent line to a circle is only applicable to lines that lie in the same plane as that of the circle as some properties of a tangent line tend to break down with a change in plane. For example if the centre and the point of contact of the tangent with the circle are joined, we get a line segment perpendicular to the tangent. This property is not always true if the plane is changed.

Now, my definition of a cone with a circular base uses the fact that tangent lines to a circle may be drawn from a point not lying in the circle's plane. According to it

> A cone is a locus of all lines which intersect a circular base and a point not lying on it.

**Can this be considered a definition of a cone?**

Comment: Instead of changing the meaning of the term tangent line, why not just put something like "... locus of all lines which intersect a circular base and a point not lying ..."?

Comment: @Bye_World So you mean to say that tangent lines lie in the same plane to that of the circle? If so, i will change my definition as you said. Would it still be valid?

Comment: The tangent line to a circle *is* always in the plane of the circle.  If it weren't then we wouldn't have uniqueness and thus wouldn't be able to say *the* tangent line to a point on the circle.

Comment: @Bye_World Is the definition making any sense now?

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Note that you won't necessarily get a *right* cone.  And you get a degenerate infinite double triangle type object if the point is in the plane of the circle but outside the circle.  And another degenerate state if the point is in the plane and *within* the circle (can you figure out what this degenerate shape would be?).  Those all seem reasonable to me.  I should say that I'm not a geometer, though, so more specialized mathematicians may or may not accept this definition.